# Sum rows of grouped data frame based on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame where I would like to create new column from the sum of different rows within one group `df["NEW_Salary"]`.
If grouped `df` by the column `Year`, `month` & `day` , I want to for each group to sum the rows where `Combination` is `True` to the rows where `Combination` is `False`.

```
    import pandas as pd
    
 data = {"Year":[2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2010,2010,2010,2010,2010],
        "Name":['Jason','Tom','KimJason','KimTom','Kim','Jason','Tom','KimJason','KimTom','Kim'],
        "Combination":[False,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,False],
        "Salary":[10,20,25,25,30,20,30,35,35,40]
        }
    df=pd.dataframe(data)

 Year  Month  Day        Name     Combination  Salary
0   2002      1   15     Jason        False      10
1   2002      1   15       Tom        False      20
2   2002      1   15  KimJason         True      25
3   2002      1   15    KimTom         True      25
4   2002      1   15       Kim        False      30
5   2010      3   20     Jason        False      20
6   2010      3   20       Tom        False      30
7   2010      3   20  KimJason         True      35
8   2010      3   20    KimTom         True      35
9   2010      3   20       Kim        False      40
10  2002      4    5      Mary        False      10
11  2002      4    5   MaryTom         True      20
12  2002      4    5       Tom        False      30
```

`df["New_Salary"]` would be created as following:

1. The row where `Name` is `KimJason`,`Salary` would be added to the `Salary` rows where `Name` is `Kim` & `Jason`
2. The row where `Name` is `KimTom`, `Salary` would be added again to the `Salary` rows where `Name` is `Kim`& `Tom`
3. The rows of `KimTom` & `KimJason` would be the same in the new column `NEW_Salary` as in `Salary`

**The expected output:**

```
       Year  Month  Day   Name  Combination  Salary    NEW_Salary
0   2002      1   15     Jason        False      10          35
1   2002      1   15       Tom        False      20          45
2   2002      1   15  KimJason         True      25          25
3   2002      1   15    KimTom         True      25          25
4   2002      1   15       Kim        False      30          80
5   2010      3   20     Jason        False      20          55
6   2010      3   20       Tom        False      30          65
7   2010      3   20  KimJason         True      35          35
8   2010      3   20    KimTom         True      35          35
9   2010      3   20       Kim        False      40         110
10  2002      4    5      Mary        False      10          30
11  2002      4    5   MaryTom         True      20          20
12  2002      4    5       Tom        False      30          50
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this output? no matter how many groups I have ?

Answer (score 1):

Here`s how you can do it, as far I can tell, it should also work for any groups.

First extract all rows with combination names to a dictionary

```py
lookup = dict(tuple(df.loc[df['Combination']==True].groupby('Name')[['Year', 'Salary']]))
for key,value in lookup.items():
    print(f"{key=}:\n{value}")
```

which looks like this: (value to each key is a df)

```
key='KimJason':
   Year  Salary
2  2002      25
7  2010      35
key='KimTom':
   Year  Salary
3  2002      25
8  2010      35
```

Then filter for rows where `Combination` is `False`, apply row by row the value of `Salary` and add all values which are found for that name and year in the lookup dictionary. At the end update the df with the new `Salary` values.

```py
s = (df.loc[df['Combination']==False]
     .apply(lambda row: 
            row['Salary'] + sum(lookup[x].loc[lookup[x]['Year']==row['Year'], 'Salary'].squeeze()
                                for x in lookup 
                                if row['Name'] in x)
            ,axis=1)
    )
df['Salary'].update(s)
print(df)
```

Output `df`:

```
   Year      Name  Combination  Salary
0  2002     Jason        False      35
1  2002       Tom        False      45
2  2002  KimJason         True      25
3  2002    KimTom         True      25
4  2002       Kim        False      80
5  2010     Jason        False      55
6  2010       Tom        False      65
7  2010  KimJason         True      35
8  2010    KimTom         True      35
9  2010       Kim        False     110
```

Comment: Hi @Rabinzel, thanks a lot for your answer. It's great. Would that work as well if I had multiple columns to group with not only Year ? let's say I have month, day & year as column for each for group

Comment: yes, that works too, it just adds some conditions to check for. maybee it is better to write a little function instead of lambda to keep things more readable then. If you provide more data, I can adjust my answer to it.

Comment: I updated my question. now the dataframe would be grouped by three columns Year, month & day. & one group has three rows. I would like to add the rows where combination is True for the rows where combination is false.  Thank you @Rabinzel